# Unable to change SharePoint account password in SharePoint 2010

Tags: authentication, user-accounts, service-account, password

I was trying to start **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service**

But it threw 
*The password for the account domainName\empID, as currently stored in SharePoint, is not the same as the current password for the account within Active Directory*

I recently changed my domain Password.So that is the possible reason.

But, I also updated the new password in the application pools.

and still getting the same error. what wrong?

where should I need to change the password to make work it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010, accounts for Farms, Web Applications and Service App pools can be set from a central location in Central Admin called "Managed Account".

Visit this technet blog for the detailed explanation on Managed Accounts - http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2011/01/25/updating-passwords-on-sharepoint-2010.aspx

In your case, follow these steps to change the password for SharePoint,

- Open up the SharePoint PowerShell command prompt
- `Set-SPManagedAccount - UseExistingPassword -Identity DOMAINA\SPSAdmin`
- Where DOMAINA\SPSAdmin is service account that had it's password changed in the AD
- You will then be prompted for the existing\new password for
  "DOMAINA\SPSAdmin"
- Run "Repair-SPManagedAccountDeployment" to verify
  the passwords are now in sync
- Next do an IISRESET command
- Run `Repair-SPManagedAccountDeployment` to verify that you do not get this
  message: `Repair-SPManagedAccountDeployment` : The password for the
  account `DOMAINA\spsadmin`, as currently stored in SharePoint, is not
  the same as the current password for the account within Active
  Directory. To fix this with PowerShell, run `Set-SPManagedAccount -UseExistingPassword`
- The `Set-SPManagedAccount -UseExistingPassword` command will update the config database and service using by this
  account.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked. Could you please tell me how to change this identiey. I want to change this user.

Comment: You can add a new managed account using the `New-SPManagedAccount` command. Please refer this blog for details - http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2010/04/11/managed-accounts.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, Deepu. Yesterday  my team entire half day was lost because of this issue. the special id created for install, spfarm account was went for a toss because of account locked out issue, and i have run the set-spmanagedaccount cmdlet and repair-spmanagedaccountdeployment comdlet as well now  its working fine. --- _/\_ pranaamam...