# Error adding server to SharePoint farm

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

When I try to add another server to my existing SharePoint 2010 farm through the configuration wizard, the wizard gets to task 3 of 9 then comes back with the message:

> Configuration Failed.

The error I get to in the log says this:

> 09/19/2012 18:25:54  11  ERR                          Task configdb has failed with an unknown exception 
>   09/19/2012 18:25:54  11  ERR                          Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The password for the account PDI\svc_sp_app_u, as currently stored in SharePoint, is not the same as the current password for the account within Active Directory. To fix this with PowerShell, run Set-SPManagedAccount -UseExistingPassword.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWindowsServiceInstance.Start()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWindowsServiceInstance.Provision(Boolean start)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Join()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

So I did some research and followed the steps on this page:
[Unable to change SharePoint account password in SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30312/unable-to-change-sharepoint-account-password-in-sharepoint-2010)

with no success.  When I first tried to add this new server, SharePoint crashed on the existing WFE because some of my service accounts were expired. So I reset the passwords in AD. Used the `Set-SPManagedAccount -UseExistingPassword` command, and called `Repair-SPManagedAccountDeployment` to verify.  Both servers have been restarted since.  SharePoint seems to be running fine on my first WFE now, but I am still getting this error when trying to add this new server.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer, and it doesnt have anything to do with the error message I was getting.  My farm account was configured in AD to only logon to my first WFE machine, and not the one I was trying to add.  An accurate error message would have been nice!  Thanks Microsoft!

Comment: useful error messages are unhip or to say it in SP-words: "Sorry, something went wrong"...